# [ODBC Destination [16]]: There was an error while trying to get schema information. The table has no supporting columns

Tags: mysql, ssis, odbc, etl

When going to column mapping in SSIS package following error occurred and cannot map the source and destination columns.

> Error at Data Flow Task [ODBC Destination [16]]: There was an error while trying to get schema information. The table has no supporting columns

This occurred in MySQL ODBC destination table and Source is SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for this. This occurs when the Destination table column contains some special characters in the column name.

1. drop the table
2. Get the create statement of the destination table and paste it on
   the notepad and remove the special character and created the table
   again

### or

3. Create the table using a query tool is also works.